# Android Bluetooth api capabilities

Tags: android

I am working with sensor devices that transmit data via bluetooth. I am using HTC desire which runs on android 2.1 platform to pair it with the sensors. I want to find out a few things about the sensor device such as its bluetooth version, what bluetooth profile it supports and its bluetooth class. My question is, is android bt api capable of extracting such information from the sensor devices. If not can you recommend any other way to get such information.

Comment: Doesn't Android support a limited set of bluetooth profiles only? Are you already able to obtain the data from your sensor devices?

Comment: Not yet but the api is capable, I've check the references. At the moment my phone sees the sensor device. Will it help me  if I connect the two together and exchange data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, initiate a discovery on your HTC and get the BluetoothDevice of your sensor (put a listener on BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND). Then when your phone discovers the remote device do: BluetoothClass btClass = btDevice.getBluetoothClass();

btClass should have everything you need.